# Como aplicar classe CSS somente em item selecionado ou limpar classe CSS aplicada em ion-radio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Sou novo em desenvolvimento angular/ionic e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que preciso selecionar um item de um `radio` e aplicar uma classe CSS somente no item selecionado.

Do modo que está implementado estou conseguindo aplicar as classes nos itens mas ela não limpa automaticamente o item que não está mais selecionado.

```
<form id="gerarSimulado-form25" class="list">
      <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 18px;"></div>

      <ion-item class="simulado_enunciado_item">
        <h3 class ="simulado_enunciado_font">{{simulado.questao}}</h3>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-radio  ng-class="{'item_selecionado':selecionado}" ng-repeat="alternativa in simulado.alternativas" id="gerarSimulado-radio5"
                 name="simulado_num_questoes" ng-click="setSiuladoResposta(simulado._id,alternativa);selecionado = !selecionado;">

        {{alternativa}}
      </ion-radio>
</form>
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver?

Comment: Você consegue colocar um modelo funcional do seu código para que possamos ajudá-lo da melhor forma possível?

Comment: Acabei complicando um pouco mais do que deveria tentando alterar a aparência pelos controllers, um colega conseguiu resolver o problema setando a classe direto no arquivo CSS, de qualquer modo obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Seria interessante você responder a pergunta com o resultado final ao que você chegou, assim pessoas com dúvida semelhante podem achar a solução sem fazer uma nova pergunta